# Sending post parameter to a url and reading the response....how to do it..?

Tags: php, post, web-crawler

I am trying to send the post parameter to a url 
http://judis.nic.in/supremecourt/DateQry.aspx

and read the response in in php...
How to do I send and read the response...!

Thanks in advance..

My code...as Below comments

```
<?php

 $ch = curl_init();


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://judis.nic.in/supremecourt/DateQry.aspx");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "button=Submit");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlday1=01");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlday2=31");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlmonth1=01");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlmonth2=01");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlreport=A");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlyear1=2013");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "ddlyear2=2013");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

$response=curl_exec($ch); 
echo $response; 
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: What's your actual problem

Comment: I want to  send the parameters to action link in the form and read the response..

Answer (score 0):

By making use of [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Here's an example

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://judis.nic.in/supremecourt/DateQry.aspx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// say if your URL has any POST params
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=John");


// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response=curl_exec($ch);

//Display your response
echo $response;

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Concatenate the fields like this

```
//Since you are using multiple fields .. do like this 
$postFields="button=Submit&ddlday=01&ddlday2=31&ddlmonth1=01&ddlmonth2=01&ddlreport=A&ddlyear1=2013&ddlyear2=2013";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
```

Comment: @ shankar,it not working...When u click on the submit button in the url, it  opens up a new window and the result is displayed..even I checked the url and parameter that are posted in firefox firebug.. but I am not able to do it..

Comment: That is simple, you need to add another cURL parameter like `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` also it will be better if you post the code what you have tried.

Comment: even did that..but no use.. :-(